# How to prove that A=B using set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given A, B and C denotes the subset of a set, S and let C ̅ denotes the complement of C in set S. If A∩C=B∩C and A∩C ̅=B∩C ̅  . Then how to prove that A=B using set builder notation.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there exists an element $a$ in $A$ that is $\color{red}{\text{not in $B$}}$. Either $a$ is in $C$ or $a$ is in $C^{-}$.

If $a$ is in $C$, then it is in $A\cap C$. But $A\cap C$ equals $B\cap C$ by hypothesis, therefore $a$ is in $B\cap C$; in particular, $a$ is in $B$. This is a $\color{red}{\text{contradiction}}$.

If $a$ is in $C^{-}$, you are led to a contradiction similarly.

Therefore there is no element in $A$ that is not also in $B$, that is, every element in $A$ is also in $B$. Hence $A\subseteq B$.

A symmetric argument shows that $B\subseteq A$.

Since $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$, we have $A=B$.